# How to print the actual SQL query to a file?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Say, this is my query

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x=?";
```

How do I print the above query plus the bound parameter to the screen or to a file in PHP?

---

When I print `$stmt` it says:

> mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string

Here's my code:

```
if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) { 
  $stmt ->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd); 
  logToFile ("my.log", "inside mysql\n"); 
  logToFile ("my.log", $stmt);
```

Comment: If you're going to ask a question with an error, post the code!  We're not mind readers.

Comment: Here it is: 

  if ($stmt= $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
   $stmt ->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
   logToFile ("my.log","inside mysql\n");
   logToFile ("my.log",$stmt);

Comment: It makes sense to me. He has a prepared query. Being prepared, it's not stored as a string and you can't get a simple SQL query as a string from it. I'm not 100% on that, though, so I'll make this just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can log your PHP variable `$query` which contains the SQL query with parameter placeholders.

But you probably want to log the query combined with the parameter values.  This is a very common request, but this information is not exposed through the client library, so you can't read it from PHP.

You can get the query combined with the parameter values in the MySQL [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html), as you `execute()` the query.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

*Quick Answer*

Ah,  I understand now. You are trying to print an array. You need to iterate/loop through it to print each value. $stmt returns from SQLite as an array.

Try this to start:

```
foreach( $stmt as $key => $value){
    echo "Key: $key, Value: $value <br />";
}
```

*An explanation:*

What happens here is that PHP receives an array from SQL and every element in an array has a key and a value. Consider the following:

```
$myArray[0] = "ElementZero";
$myArray[1] = "ElementOne";
$myArray[2] = "ElementTwo";
...
$myArray[15] = "ElementFifteen";
```

The numbers in the square brackets (0,1,2,15) are your keys and the text in quotes are your values. This is an indexed array, where each element has an index number. An associative array is where strings are used instead of numbers to identify each item in the array.A quick example of this:

```
$myArray['bob'] = "foo";
...
$myArray['joe'] = "bar";
```

In this array, we use strings as keys instead of numbers. Personally, I only see this useful when dealing with multidimensional arrays, but that is not for now...

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Moshe, that gives out an error.
>Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string in H:\wamp\www\magicmall\classes\Mysql.php on line 29

Answer (score 0):

```
print $query;
```

but don't you know what is in $query?

try:

```
print serialize($stmt);
```

it will tell you what is in the stmt object

Actually, serialize is my favorite debugging output format.